# How are the multiple images being imported in cifar10_input.py

Tags: tensorflow

I am now going through tensorflow's cirfar10 tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) and have a question:
it seems that read_cifar10(filename_queue) fucntion in cifar10_input.py will only read in a single images each time. However, in distorted_inputs(data_dir, batch_size), read_cifar10 is only called once (line 159).

Could anyone point me to the lines where the code read in all the images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The batch function takes in one image at a time and will then output a batch once the minimum batch size has been met.

You can see it in the code [batch function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L99) you can also look here for the batch function API [batch API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch).